# Imagemagick crop pdf on one side only

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, trim, imagemagick-convert

I am using the following command line to crop **png files** from the bottom side only:

```
convert ./in.png -background white -splice 0x1 -background black -splice 0x1 -trim +repage -chop 0x1 ./out.png
```

from [this tutorial](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim_oneside).

**But a similar command does not work for pdf.** 
How can I get ImageMagick to crop/chop/trim only the bottom form a pdf?

Comment: You example shows a PNG input not a PDF input. If you really have a PDF input, then post a link to an example PDF file that does not work correctly. I can then test to see what might be the issue. I can create a PDF from the logo: image in ImageMagick with extra white at the bottom and then use your command successfully. But the issue may be a virtual canvas in your PDF embedded image. So try adding +repage right after reading the PDF.

Comment: convert ./in.pdf -background white -splice 0x1 -background black -splice 0x1 -trim +repage -chop 0x1 ./out.pdf ----------> this is what I tried and it does not work, the out.pdf file is the same as the in.pdf.

Comment: As I said above try `convert ./in.pdf +repage -background white -splice 0x1 -background black -splice 0x1 -trim +repage -chop 0x1 ./out.pdf`. If that fails, then post a link to your PDF file. What version of ImageMagick are you using and on what platform?

Comment: It works with +repage